# Iterators in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
vector<int> v(1, 1);
it = v.begin();
```

Why `*it++` didn't plus one on the first element?

Although I can use `*it  = *it + 1`

I haven't use `C++` for years

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 4):

++ has higher precedence than *.

So first iterator is made to point to next element and then de-referenced using *, you could have collected v[1] on left side.

Use code as below to fix the problem.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> v(2, 1);
vector<int>::iterator it;
it = v.begin();
(*it)++; //instead of *it++;

cout << v[0] <<  v[1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: I could not get this code to compile. What am I missing? Here's the code at ideone.com - http://shar.es/5gmnM

Answer (score 0):

Because `*it++` means to postincrement `it` and dereference the result (the original value of `it`) since the `++` binds tighter (it's equivalent to `*(it++)`). It does not modify the contents at `*it`. If you want to increment `*it`, use `(*it)++`.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It means `it++`, and dereference the result.  The result of a post-increment is the value the iterator had before being incremented.  And post-increment on iterators can be inefficient.

Comment: what he means is the post increment fires first, and the result that is returned for deref is the *prior* element. Thus the expensive part.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My mental model of `*s++` is that the increment happens after the dereference, but the operator precedence calls it "postincrement then dereference".

Comment: @WhozCraig: The potentially expensive part is the copy that postincrement has to make of the original iterator, before it gets advanced.  Depending on the iterator type, a copy may be very cheap or quite costly.

Comment: @BenVoigt Precisely. The expensive part =) (or maybe... not=P)

Comment: @nneonneo: Your mental model is wrong though.  What if the dereference involved a function call (quite possible, since `operator*` is overloadable, and frequently IS overloaded on iterator types), and that function looked at the value of `it`.  It could definitely see the after-increment value.  The expression `it++` evaluates to the value `it` held before the increment (by convention, nothing in the language enforces this on a custom operator implementation), but `it` itself is adjusted first.

Comment: Only if the function looked at `it` and not the value that was passed to it. But this is a very good point to keep in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As others  have explained

```
int x = *it++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int x = (*it)++;
```

which is equivalent to

```
int x = *it;
it = ++it; // prefix
```

**it** is not incremented until after the semicolon (because it is the postfix operator).
The posfix ++ operator is usually implemented using the prefix operator like this

```
template<typename T> vector<T>::iterator vector<typename T>::iterator::operator++(int)
{
   vector<T>::iterator tmp(*this);
   ++(*this); // call prefix operator++()
   return tmp;   
}
```

where you can see that it returns the value of the iterator before operator++() is done.